# Python nmap not showing same results as terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmap

Unsure how to phrase this, as I am new to Python.

Basically, I have this method in Python (below) that is scanning for devices available on my network. The Python code returns only 6 devices, and not the one I am searching for (Roku)

```
def scanner(self):
        """
            Method that scans the network for available IP addresses.
        """
        if len(self.ip) == 0:
            network = '192.168.1.0/24'
        else:
            network = self.ip + '/24'

        print("Scanning please wait...")

        nm = nmap.PortScanner()
        nm.scan(hosts=network, arguments='-sn')
        host_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]

        for item in nm.all_hosts():
            print(item)

        for host, status in host_list:
            self.ip_addresses.append(host)

        self.choose_address()
```

When I use `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` in my terminal, I get back 9 devices, including the Roku. Does anyone have any insight into why this doesn't want to work for me?

Comment: You are running the **nmap** with **sudo**, is your Python script running using sudo?

Comment: That makes total sense and is absolutely what's happening. Is there a way to run nmap inside of a python program as sudo?

Comment: The easy solution that comes to my mind now would be to run the Python script with sudo, but not sure if that's the best one.